# How can I set an analytics goal for any product page?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I'm developing an E-Commerce site and I want to set-up a Google Analytics Goal for whenever a user visits any product page. However, the product pages are all in different categories and have different urls.

Comment: Can you provide examples of the product pages? For example, do their URLs follow a particular pattern, like `/page/product/X`?

Comment: At the moment no, due to the way the plebs at the company are uploading products via CMS. But I could fix all the urls if this will help? The chain would be domain/products/x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 approaches you could take.

The preferable way is for you to unify the product page URLs to meet a particular pattern, so that you could configure the goal to be a Head Match on that pattern.

ie, if your gimzo product URL is domain/products/gizmo, and your widget product URL is domain/products/widget, you could set the goal to trigger for viewing `/domain/products` as a head match.

Or, you could just set a new pageview/event for every product pageview. ie, on the product page, set an additional event to lock the goal against. (The drawback to this approach is that it messes with bounce and exit rate numbers.)

Now, the one caveat with these approaches is that a single goal can only trigger once per visit, so, your "Goal" will only trigger once, even if I view 4 product pages in my visit.

Comment: Oh, so this would be the same with a goal for "click add to cart button" etc. I'm not actually getting accurate results at all?

Comment: @Moppy correct. Goals should be thought of in the context of "Did X desirable action happen during the visit"? They're great for providing analysis, of, say, the relative ROI of different traffic sources, or whether landing page X converts better than landing page Y. They can't do everything, though.